# c# nullreference for save on load streamreader/writer

Tags: c#

I've made a program and I want to save the data. Saving is working, but "Loading" doesn't work.

```
    public void Save(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buecher.Count; i++)
        {
            Buch b = (Buch)buecher[i];
            if (i == 0)
                sw.WriteLine("ISDN ; Autor ; Titel");
            sw.WriteLine(b.ISDN + ";" + b.Autor + ";" + b.Titel);
        }
    }

    public void Load(StreamReader sr)
    {
        int isd;
        string aut;
        string tit;

        while (sr.ReadLine() != "")
        {
            string[] teile = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
            try
            {
                isd = Convert.ToInt32(teile[0]);
                aut = teile[1];
                tit = teile[2];
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("umwandlung fehlgeschlagen");

            }
            Buch b = new Buch(isd, aut, tit);
            buecher.Add(b);

        }

    }
```

If I'm doing that with an break after `buecher.Add(b);` than its everything fine but it obviously shows me only 1 book... if I'm not using the break he gives me an error "nullreference.."

Would be awesome if someone could help me
best regards
Ramon

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are reading two lines for each iteration in the loop (and throwing away the first one). If there are an odd number of lines in the file, the second call to `Read` will return `null`.

Read the line into a variable in the condition, and use that variable in the loop:

```
public void Load(StreamReader sr) {
  int isd;
  string aut;
  string tit;

  // skip header
  sr.ReadLine();

  string line;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (line.Length > 0) {
      string[] teile = line.Split(';');
      try {
        isd = Convert.ToInt32(teile[0]);
        aut = teile[1];
        tit = teile[2];
      } catch {
        throw new Exception("umwandlung fehlgeschlagen");
      }
      Buch b = new Buch(isd, aut, tit);
      buecher.Add(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm i see ..@ guffa that code isn t working                                        it throw me an exception                                                     catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("umwandlung fehlgeschlagen");
                    }

Comment: @RamonHämmerle are you sure your file is right? Keep in mind it will throw if the first item on a line isn't a valid integer, or if a line doesn't contain 3 times. There are no checks there to ensure it's good.

Comment: well there are no mistakes .. everything works fine with the break and if im doing it with your code and the ,,pause" + f11 its always null in aut / tit and 0 in isd but in my code it even writes the stuff in it  but in the 2nd loop it throws the nullref..

Comment: this is the right approach, but doesn't it need to skip the header? the first line has `ISDN ; Auter ; Titel` so you will be calling `Convert.ToInt32` on `"ISDN "`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: isdn is a number aut ? author and titel = title so 2 strings and 1 int ^^

Comment: @RamonHämmerle I know, but there is a "header". The first line literally says `"ISDN ; Auter ; Titel"` and `"ISDN "` can't be converted to an integer. You have to skip the first line in the data file. Otherwise you will get a `FormatException`, which will be caught by the `catch` block, and you will get the `umwandlung fehlgeschlagen` exception.

Comment: @RamonHämmerle the header line is generated by the line: `if (i == 0) sw.WriteLine("ISDN ; Autor ; Titel");`

Comment: @RamonHämmerle: Sahuagin is correct, there is a header line in the file. You didn't encounter it before, as it was one of the lines that were thrown away. I added code to skip the header.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `sr.ReadLine()` twice for every line, once in the `while()` and once right after. You are hitting the end of the file, which returns a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach to this but I suggest it because it's simpler;

```
 Load(string filepath)
 {
     try
     {
         List<Buch> buches = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
                             .Select(x => new Buch(int.Parse(x.Split(';')[0]), x.Split(';')[1], x.Split(';')[2]));
     {
     catch
     {
         throw new Exception("umwandlung fehlgeschlagen");
     }

 }
```

You could do it in more lines if you find it to be more readable but I've come to prefer `File.ReadAllText` and `File.ReadAllLines` to `StreamReader` approach of reading files.

Instead of using the LINQ statement you could also do;

```
 Load(string filepath)
 {
     try
     {
         string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
         foreach (string line in lines)
         {
             string[] tokens = line.Split(';');
             if (tokens.Length != 3)
                // error
             int isd;
             if (!int.TryParse(tokens[0], out isd))
                //error, wasn't an int
             buetcher.Add(new Buch(isd, tokens[1], tokens[2]);
         }

     {
     catch
     {
         throw new Exception("umwandlung fehlgeschlagen");
     }

 }
```

Comment: thats to high for me sorry ... im still at basics of c#

Comment: @RamonHämmerle I added some other code that is more similar to what you have, just using `File.ReadAllLines` instead of a `StreamReader` and also it has some basic input validation.

Comment: Consider using `foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filepath))`. That way you don't have to read the entire file into memory.